# How can I custom sender and header on send mail layout laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail, laravel-5.3

My code is like this :

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('You have new follower')
                ->greeting('Hello!')
                ->line('Welcome to my application')
                ->line('Thank you');
}
```

The result is like this : [image]

See I marked in blue. I want to custom that.

I read on https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#mail-notifications, but I did not find it

How do I custom it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to change your configurations.

`config/app.php` change the `name` value to whatever you like
and in the `config/mail.php` you can edit the `from` values.

If you want the from to be different than the default from, you can call the `from` method in your `MailMessage` chain.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('You have new follower')
                ->from('cthulhu@microsoft.com', 'Moses Toh')
                ->greeting('Hello!')
                ->line('Welcome to my application')
                ->line('Thank you');
}
```

Further if you want to actually modify the layout/html/css of the email check the section **Customizing The Templates** here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#mail-notifications

> You can modify the HTML and plain-text template used by mail notifications by publishing the notification package's resources. After running this command, the mail notification templates will be located in the `resources/views/vendor/notifications` directory:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`